# F#: Downloading data asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
open System.IO
open System.Net

let downloadHtmlFromUrlAsync (url: string) =
    async { 
        let uri = new System.Uri(url)
        let webClient = new WebClient()
        let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
        return html
        }

let downloadHtmlToDisk (url: string) (directoryPath: string) = 
    if isValidUrl url then
        let name = getNameFromRedirectedUrl url
        let id = getIdFromUrl url
        let html = downloadHtmlFromUrlAsync url
        let newTextFile = File.Create(directoryPath + "\\" + id.ToString("00000") + " " + name.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
        use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
        file.Write(html) 
        file.Close()

let downloadEntireDatabase (baseUrl: string) (totalNumberOfPeople: int) = 
    let allIds = [ for i in 1 .. totalNumberOfPeople -> i ]

    allIds
    |> Seq.map (fun id -> baseUrl + string(id))
    |> Seq.filter isValidUrl
    |> Seq.map downloadHtmlToDisk
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I have tested the functions isValidUrl, getNameFromRedirectedUrl, getIdFromUrl in F# interactive. They work fine.

My problem is this: When I try to run the code pasted above, the following error message is produced:

> Program.fs(483,8): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
>       `seq<(string -> unit)>`     is not compatible with type
>       `seq<Async<'a>>`     The type `Async<'a>` does not match the type `string -> unit`

What went wrong? What changes should I make?

Comment: where is at least: `downloadFighterHtmlToDisk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably this line (can you please give us the definition of `downloadFighterHtmlToDisk`):

```
  allIds
    ...
    |> Seq.map downloadFighterHtmlToDisk
    ...
```

based on the error message this functions seems to have a signature `string -> string -> unit` but you really need `string -> Async<'something>`.

Now I guess you used `downloadHtmlToDisk` or something similar and you can but then I would suggest rewriting it to:

```
let downloadHtmlToDisk (directoryPath: string) (url: string) = 
    async {
        if isValidUrl url then
            let name = getNameFromRedirectedUrl url
            let id = getIdFromUrl url
            let! html = downloadHtmlFromUrlAsync url
            let newTextFile = File.Create(directoryPath + "\\" + id.ToString("00000") + " " + name.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
            use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
            file.Write(html) 
    }
```

and use it like

```
 let downloadEntireDatabase (baseUrl: string) (totalNumberOfPeople: int) = 
        let allIds = [ for i in 1 .. totalNumberOfPeople -> i ]

        allIds
        |> Seq.map (fun id -> (id, baseUrl + string(id)))
        |> Seq.filter (fun (_,url) -> isValidUrl url)
        |> Seq.map (fun (id,url) -> downloadHtmlToDisk (getFighterPath id) url)
        |> Async.Parallel 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

**See** the `let! html = ..`? This is important - this is where the `async` will happen ;) - if you want you can find similar operations to write your file asynchronously. Also you don't need to close your file - dispose should handle it

### remark

I have just seen that you reextract the id from the url - you might also use this instead of the way I used tuples but I think it's better to really pass the id on if you still need it - for example in `downloadHtmlToDisk` you really need the `id` and could have created the `url` from the `id` there instead - a much easier approach IMO but I don't want to rewrite everything you go - just experiment a bit with this stuff

Comment: Thanks, Carsten. I have a follow-up question: How may I specify the maximum number of threads to employ when I call Async.Parallel?

Comment: You cannot directly - basically you have to group up the work into your desired blocks and pass those to Async.Parallel - or trust in the ThreadPool ;)